# Repeated and unique in hash-like things

Tags: raku

The [`repeated`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/repeated) method takes a function as an argument for normalizing the elements before finding out which ones are repeated. However, I can't seen to make it work with `values`. For instance:

```
%(:a(3),:b(3),:c(2)).repeated( as=> *.values ).say
```

Returns an empty list, while I was expecting the pairs :a(3) and :b(3), same as

```
%(:a(3),:b(3),:c(2)).repeated( as=> .values ).say
```

In this case, for instance, it seems to work as expected:

```
(3+3i, 3+2i, 2+1i).unique(as => *.re).say  # OUTPUT: «(3+3i 2+1i)␤»
```

Any idea of what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`.values`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/values) is a method for returning all of the values of a container.

Since it is a [List](https://docs.perl6.org/type/List) method, if you call it on a singular value it pretends it is a [List](https://docs.perl6.org/type/List) containing only that value.

```perl6
say 5.values.perl;
# (5,)
```

---

The `as` named parameter of [`.repeated`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/repeated) gets called on all of the singular values.

```perl6
%(:a(3),:b(3),:c(2)).repeated( as=> *.perl.say );
# :a(3)
# :b(3)
# :c(2)
```

So by giving it the `*.values` lambda, it is effectively not doing anything useful.

---

The method you were looking for is [`.value`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/value). Which is a method on a [Pair](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Pair).

```perl6
%(:a(3),:b(3),:c(2)).repeated( as=> *.value ).say
# (a => 3)
```